# Big Redis setup

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I need to store 32M records in Redis 3.0.1, each record needs around 422KB. Making a total of around 13GB of information.

The information is stored in disc in a zipped hashlist, and serialized in smile jackson. I'm using Java 6, Jedis and AIX.

I have a few questions:

1. Does that mean that the Redis process needs 13GB or RAM?
2. Is this a manageable size for a single instance or would you go for a cluster setup? I think we can have up to 4 servers. This would mean revisit the whole project and dates, so please consider other management impacts on this question.
3. Is there a better way of storing this amount of data?

Thanks

Carlos

Comment: Is your math off here?  422KB x 32,000,000 = 13504000000KB / 1024 = 13187500MB / 1000 = 13187GB

Comment: You're query pattern of the data is important, it's impossible to know if you need it in-memory (Redis) for some reason, or on disk (RDBMS/NoSQL) etc without knowing how you need to query that data.  Any of those things will work, but each is better suited to a particular use case

Comment: @Alex Also, the OP should consider gzipping values...

Comment: Thanks Alex. Yes, it seems my math wasn't accurate, making the problem even more serious. The reason to use Redis is to obtain customer information in a very fast way. Right now it's beign done using Oracle, but we want to cut the response time from hundreds of ms to 30 or 40ms. Each customer has a unique numeric identifier, which is the key for the HashMap. This key is also bucketed, making a total of 1000 buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you use a Redis Cluster, all of your data should fit in memory.
With 13TB of data, as pointed by Alex, and limited to 4 servers as you said, it means each server should have more than 4TB of RAM...

Moreover Redis stores the data in memory in a format that is optimised for speed, and so does not try very hard to reduce their size. So it may take more than 13TB in practice.
That's why I would not recommend Redis in this case, or at least not Redis only.
Maybe you should consider an alternative NoSQL Database, that offer fast response time although it stores data on disk, like Couchbase (it uses Redis internaly as a cache).

Or, if your use case allows it, an easiest solution would be to add a Redis cache to your current architecture, without changing the current database you use. It will dramaticaly improve the access speed to data in cache (but wont reduce the first access). It depends if the data are likely to be requested more than once in a short period of time, or not.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I like your approach. But what about the serializer? I know it's not Redis-specific, but what I'm doing is serializing Java pojos using Jackson for Smile: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonForSmile

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see why it would impact the database. Redis isn't aware of the type of data you store. It will just give you back what you insert.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was just thinking that a better serializer would reduce the memory needs. But that would be another thread. Thanks for your answer.